# How do I binding dynamic img src w/require

Tags: vue.js

How can I bind the following dynamically? It’s for user feedback in case of an error, so I’d like to avoid rendering it unless needed.

I’m using the vuetify boilerplate. This works when inside the template as is:

```
v-img :src="require('../assets/error.png')"
```

I’d like to set it dynamically :src=null to :src="errorImg" when receiving an error. The require is throwing me off.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you use `v-img src="../assets/error.png"` or `v-img :src="myDynamicImage"` where `myDynamicImage` is a string which is set to error when there is an error or the actual url otherwise

Comment: Note that you can also make use of the `lazy-src` prop on `v-img`

Comment: Use `v-if="showErrorImage"`. You create variable that you can toggle and image will show/hide

Comment: @smac89 If I use v-img src="../assets/error.png" I get an error saying image load failed

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

if error

```
this.errorImg = require("../assets/error.png");
```